# Why ng-pattern return false all the time inside a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a input directive, where when the user enters anything other than a number, I want the box to turn red. I was able to solve this by following

```
<input ng-model='numberNoDir' type='text' ng-pattern='/^\d*$/'>
```

but when I put it in a directive then it always return false and even if I enter a number. [Here is the Plunker of to reproduce the problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/ix0ANFz4JpbrkqDDr6YU). I have this a compile than link since it need to replace current DOM with new DOM. Is it correct approach to use compile here rather than link? and also why is directive always return false?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\` character in a JavaScript is the escape character.  It works in your HTML because `\` is not used to escape anything in HTML.  You need to use `\\` in your directive.  You probably already know this, but didn't realize that was your issue.  :)

There's also no need to $compile your template or use the transclude option if your template isn't going to use the `ngTransclude` directive.  Your directive can be fixed and simplified as:

```
app.directive("numberInput", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            fooBar: "=ngModel"
        },
        require: "ngModel",
        template: "<input type='text' ng-model='fooBar' ng-pattern='/^\\d*$/'>"
    }
});
```

Comment: wow totally forgot about \\, i keep thinking I was messing up something in the compiler or linking.thanks a ton